# Why doesn't sed interpret this regex properly?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

```
echo "This is a test string" | sed 's/This/\0/'
```

First I match substring `This` using the regex `This`. Then I replace the entire string with the first match using `\0`. So the result should be just the matched string.

But it prints out the entire line. Why is this so?

Comment: What do you want to print with `\0`? Literally, the string `\0`?

Comment: @fedorqui No I intend to use the first regex match not the literal string `\0`

Comment: As pfnuesel says, you are replacing a string with the same string, so the result is the same. Do for example `sed 's/This/\0AA/'` to see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't replace the whole string with `\0`, just the pattern match, which is `This`. In other words, you replace `This` with `This`.

To replace the whole line with `This`, you can do:

```
echo "This is a test string" | sed '/This/s/.*/This/'
```

It looks for a line matching `This`, and replaces the whole line with `This`. In this case (since there is only one line) you can also do:

```
echo "This is a test string" | sed 's/.*/This/'
```

If you want to reuse the match, then you can do

```
echo "This is a test string" | sed 's/.*\(This\).*/\1/'
```

`\(` and `\)` are used to remember the match inside them. It can be referenced as `\1` (if you have more than one pair of `\(` and `\)`, then you can also use `\2`, `\3`, ...).

In the example above this is not very helpful, since we know that inside `\(` and `\)` is the word `This`, but if we have a regex inside the parentheses that can match different words, this can be very helpful.

Comment: The replacement has to be selected out of the string. Perhaps I used a wrong example to illustrate my problem. I need to select a number using `\d\d\d\d` and then use it as replacement. So your suggestion won't work.

Comment: sed requires you escape parenthesis for some reason, try `.*(This).*`  on regexpal.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/.*\(PatThis\).*/PatThat/'
```

or

```
se '/PatThis/ s/.*/PatThat/'
```

In your request "PatThis" and "PatThat" are the same contain ("This"). In the comment (

> I need to select a number using \d\d\d\d and then use it as
>   replacement

) you have 2 different value for the pattern PatThis and PatThat
the \1 is not really needed because you know the exact contain (unless 'PatThis' is a regex with special char like \ & ? .)